# Is it possible to install App in iPhone directly without iTunes or Appstore?

Tags: iphone, applications, install

Android apps can be directly installed from apk files from Android phones.

Is it possible to install iPhone App in iPhone directly without using iTunes or Appstore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply - No, not without Jailbreaking it.

Answer (score 3):

It's been possible to install (or 'sideload') apps onto iOS devices without a jailbreak or iTunes (though iTunes may need to be installed) for a year or two now. There's a few applications (e.g. Saurik's [Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/), CopyTrans, Appandora) around to do this, and one can also use Xcode (see [here](http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/12/howto-sideload-apps-iphone-ipad-xcode/)).

This is something that will be of inccreasing interest now since Apple has recently removed the app store from iTunes 12.7, although it seems that Apple says it will still be possible to [use iTunes to transfer apps](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201593).